# Hide li tag if there is data in database else show li tag

Tags: php, laravel, html-lists

i want to disable my li tag if there is no data in database for particular id

and enable it if a record is there.

this is code :

```
<ul class="pagination no-padding">
       <li class="">
            <a href="#" onclick="window.history.back()">&laquo;</a>
       </li>
</ul>
```

this is my controller function:

```
public function nextquery($id)
    {
        $query = $id;
        $inc = $id + 1;
        $next_query = DB::table('tbl_query_master')->select('*')
                      ->where('id',$inc)->first();

        return view('QueryMaster.show_query')
            ->with('next_query',$next_query)
    }
```

Comment: You mean hide and show li ?

Comment: Then check value of `next_query` and act accordingly.

Comment: Can't believe you could do a query construction but you can't perform a simple comparation block.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
<ul class="pagination no-padding">
            @if($next_query !== null)
               <li class="">
                    <a href="#" onclick="window.history.back()">&laquo;</a>
               </li>
            @endif
</ul>
```